# Docker + SSL + apache2 + x509

Tags: ssl, amazon-ec2, docker, apache2, x509certificate

I have a biggest problem for me: SSL
I'm trying install a certificate in my system, and my system have 3 containers that are manage with vagrant.

database (docker)
main System (docker)
proxy(docker) - that's a proxy reverse

When I try install in my container proxy, and install all certificates on folders.
I change in the

```
<Virtualhost>

    ## SSL directives
      SSLEngine on
      SSLCertificateFile       "/etc/apache2/ssl/www.mydomain.com.br.crt"
      SSLCertificateKeyFile "/etc/apache2/ssl/mykey.key"
      SSLCACertificateFile  "/etc/apache2ssl/sslroot.crt"
      SSLCertificateChainFile "/etc/apach2/ssl/Intermediate.crt"

</Virtualhost>
```

And obviously my certificates in path folders /etc/apache2/ssl/

When I try restart my Apache, my container "proxy" don't running again and their status is as stoped. Thein I call docker log proxy:

```
***[error] Init: Unable to read server certificate from file /etc/apache2/ssl/www.patobragado.gedvic.com.br.key
[Thu Aug 06 11:01:02 2015] [error] SSL Library Error: 218529960 error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_CHECK_TLEN:wrong tag
[Thu Aug 06 11:01:02 2015] [error] SSL Library Error: 218595386 error:0D07803A:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_ITEM_EX_D2I:nested asn1 error***
```

Someone know how I can solve this problem?

I need much install this SSL in server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you started your proxy container by linking it correctly to your webserver container like:

```
docker run -d --name webserver ...
docker run -d --name proxy --link webserver ...
```

When you restart the `webserver` container its internal Docker IP address might be changed after reboot and the `/etc/hosts` file on the `proxy` container [gets automatically updated as well](https://docs.docker.com/reference/run/#env-environment-variables). So I *guess* that when the `proxy` suddenly connects to a different IP address that breaks SSL.

So you also need to reboot your `proxy` (or just reload its configuration inside the container if possible to re-initialize the SSL configuration).

I did not test it, yet. But you could also try to define a *restart policy* on your `proxy` container like:

```
docker run -d --name proxy --link webserver --restart=always ...
```